# Laravel pagination with distinct

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to use distinct with pagination but my pagination seems to ignore the total records of my distinct and it makes my pagination all messed up.

I have the following query:

```
$log_data_list = DB::table('logs')->leftjoin('users','logs.user_id', 'users.id')
        ->select(DB::raw("distinct on (logs.action,logs.action_table)logs.user_id,users.username as username,logs.created_at as tanggal,logs.ip_client as ip_client,logs.action as tindakan,logs.action_table as tabel,logs.no_laka as no_laka,logs.change_id as id"))
        ->paginate(5);
```

Can anyone help me with a solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a distinct in this fashion, why not have the log actions stored **uniquely** in a relational table using methods firstOrCreate / firstOrNew on storing the actual log.
You then would be able to use a proper eloquent model to paginate log actions table that would already be a unique list and use the ID of selection action to get all related logs.

table.logs id,action_id,users_id,...

table.logs_actions id,action_name

This would be less costly than a select distinct especially on a huge table.

Comment: i cant do that, the log table is for user activity so theres always be duplicate

Comment: Of course, that is why firstOrNew will help you build a second table of unique actions, you can use the returned ID on the actual user log instead of the storing the action name which is repetitive data.Its best practice to store repetitive data in a relational table.
I strongly suggest reading up on relational tables in the laravel docs to understand how you can store the "actions" in separate unique list. I have built one myself in this manner. Its better than using distinct by far.